# Grails g:select tag with small picture for each option

Tags: html, css, grails, select, gsp

Is it possible to have a picture per option in  tag? The select list is going to show different file extensions (e.g. xls, pdf, csv, etc.). I would like to have the picture shown based on the file extension type.

If it can only be done using css, could you inform how each one will have different picture?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways to achieve this.  None of which will work using the g:select tag directly.  The simplest of which is probably just using CSS to provide a background-image for each option element as well as some slight positioning CSS.

For a more 'out of the box' solution you might look at something like [this](http://www.marghoobsuleman.com/jquery-image-dropdown).